# bless object instances with methods from a separate service

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

### Background

I have a service that queries and returns delivery timeslots for multiple stores and a date range. Alongside of this, I have a separate service to query the capacity information for the timeslots that will be returned (our capacity management system is not directly related to timeslots, but is defined by time ranges).

### Problem

Each individual timeslot object has a method called `enough_capacity?` that performs a lookup each time to determine the capacity limits for that single timeslot. However, this is not very efficient, considering that I can query a larger set of capacity information.

### Attempt

After reading up on some meta programming, I figured that I could bless each instance with a new `enough_capacity?` singleton method (it shouldn't apply to all instances) that performs a lookup based on a cached data set.

To accomplish this, I've come up with this:

```ruby
def get_blessed_delivery_timeslots(store)
  get_store_delivery_timeslots(store).each do |timeslot|
    timeslot.singleton_class.class_exec(@capacity_service) do |capacity_service|
      define_method(:enough_capacity?) { capacity_service.enough_capacity?(self) }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm using `class_exec` on the singleton class so that I can pass the capacity service into the scope. While this works, it doesn't feel right to me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That's kind of interesting, but is refactoring `enough_capacity?` not an option ?

Comment: @ThongKuah You mean refactoring `Timeslot#enough_capacity?` to take in the capacity service as an optional argument?

Comment: Yes, that would be my first attempt. However, nowadays, I would just initialize a service / query object to perform such bulk calculations. Think Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: @ThongKuah The service to perform the bulk calculations is there; the timeslot itself is an active record which should also be able to work independently ... think I found a way without metaprogramming though ;)